# How to securely download rpmfusion keys

Tags: security, key-authentication

**The Actual Problem I am trying to solve**

I am trying to automatically configure my fedora installations via salt to automatically have the rpmfusion repositories installed. In order to do this securely I need the gpg key so that packages can be verified before they are installed. However, I am unable to find a way to securely download rpmfusion's keys.

For example, if I was making a google chrome repo I would have something like this.

```
[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
```

However, for rpmfusion the closest thing I have is the following (Note this is untested):

```
[rpmfusion-nonfree]
name=RPM Fusion for Fedora $releasever - Nonfree 
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/mirrorlist?repo=nonfree-fedora-$releasever&arch=$basearch
enabled=1
metadata_expire=7d
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://rpmfusion.org/keys?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-nonfree-fedora-$releasever
```

However, note that I am download via an unencrypted channel (http instead of https). So my question is the following:

Is there a way for me to securely download rpmfusion's public key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to download keys securely, rather you can download them and confirm that they're legitimate using the steps outlined on their "keys" webpage.

- [Trusting Package Integrity](http://rpmfusion.org/keys)

*excerpt*

> Verify
>
> If you have newly installed the rpmfusion-*-release.rpm repo packages, and wish to verify its keys, check the fingerprints below.
>
> If you want to verify the key before to install the rpmfusion-*release.rpm, you can use
>
> ```
>   $ gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys Key_ID
> ```
>
> Where Key_ID is 172FF33D in the case of RPM Fusion Free for Fedora 19.

Comment: Unfortunately verifying against that keyserver is not any better! The connection isn't secured. Also anyone can post any key to the keyserver with any description.   What you really want is a signature of that key from somewhere secure. In the past I've tried googling the key id e.g. 172FF33D, as a very dumb cross-check. (Use google over HTTPS). I've also tried tracing v.s. keys I already have.